# Protractor: Locating element that contains multiple divs and no unique css to identify them

Tags: css, automation, protractor, element, e2e-testing

Just wanted to share: If you are in a situation where there are no classes within a certain section and the value of that particular div cannot be hardcoded and changes, using protractor e2e framework I have managed to locate the specific div using this method:

Adding an example of html that does not have a class for every element

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="page_banner">A Dude's Profile</div>
  <div class="profile_details">
    <div class="profile_name">
     <h3>Tony Adams</h3>
    </div>
    <div>ta@bogus.com</div>
    <div>0883424324</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the case where you need to say identify that there is a unique mobile number, so the value is not consistent.

```
function mobileNumberAssert() {
        element.all(by.css('.profile_details'))
        .get(1) // number of divs in css
        .getText()
        .then(function(textFoundInCss) {
    if(textFoundInCss > 10) {
      return true; 
       console.log('there is a mobile number present with 10 digits');
       } else {
         return false;
       }
     });
}
```

For Debugging you can console log the "textFoundInCss" working your way to locate that particular div.

Comment: This post may be useful to others if you provide an example of the element HTML that presented the issue

Comment: @DublinDev thanks for the recommendation, I've added a html sample for better understanding.

Comment: Seems that you have changed this post from its original content. Is there something you are actually needing help with?

Comment: I just wanted to share a solution to a problem i was struggling with. I updated this post to contain some sample html to better explain my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you are looking for an element based on the text you could use `by.cssContainingText()` to make this a lot easier.

```
const el = element(by.cssContainingText('div', `Text I'm looking for`);

el.isPresent().then(isPresent => {
    if (isPresent) {
        // do something ...
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: CssContainingText() is a real good way to locate an element that contains static text. The example I am using is when the text is not static, may it be an email address or a mobile number, in this particular case CssContainingText() would not work due to there being no static content.

Comment: For testing purposes, don't you know what the text is that you are looking for? I'm assuming you are trying to assert that an element contains some text that you expect to be there. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: In most cases, there are labels titles to references via text and css. In my particular case i was testing a number of Profiles which had unique data that could also be updated or changed in future and no css class to reference the element. Edge case I know, but it happened.